# How to quote all strings with spaces and newlines with csv module

Tags: python, csv

I have data such that it contains columns having number, string, date and timestamp.

I used quote_minimal but then strings with leading and trailing spaces were not getting quoted.

I used quote_nonnumeric but then it is quoting the dates as well.

The csv that I am generating I need to use that to generate a table so if spaces are not within quotes it will get trimmed and I dont want that.
If I use quote_nonnumeric then it will quote null dates so while loading in table I will get error.

Comment: Use the default settings and it should quote anything that needs to be quoted.

Comment: The default is quote_minimal only

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733181/python-csv-writer-to-quote-strings-with-extra-spaces#:~:text=Python%20default%20CSV%20writer%20has%20the%20option%20to,%28like%20libre-office%29%20strips%20the%20spaces%20if%20not%20quoted.) help?

Comment: I think your choices are either `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` or `QUOTE_ALL`, and live with some redundant quotes.

Comment: No I already saw that answer. And it doesn't even has an accepted answer. Although question is similar but even that post was not having an accepted answer so I created a new as it was old..

Comment: I dont want to quote dates and numbers as if for any row value is Null it will also quote it and when inserting into table it will be considered a char of empty string rather than a date or number so it will give error. So I need to quote only strings but with spaces

Comment: Roll your own quoting by adapting the `quote()` function in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19315648/2318649

Comment: what are you trying to do after this quoting issue is fixed? (a.k.a. what is the end goal of your question?). Are you going to add it to a pandas dataframe? if yes show the dataframe code so that we can make sure any suggested code does not cause error in your df. also, show a visual sample of what you want rather than using all words.

Comment: Please could you print out a few sample rows of the data into your question